# Запоминание голосования авторизованных пользователей

Tags: база-данных

Имеются голоса "+" и "-" к комментам, ставить которые могут только авторизованные пользователи. После голосования кнопка не должна выводится. Кто сталкивался, как запоминать кто к посту поставил голос?

Пока приходит в голову 2 варианта:

1. Записывать id-user в текстовую строку в БД и искать потом просто подстроку в строке. Например, в строке есть id проголосовавших: 1, 2, 3. Сейчас авторизован id-user_2, значит кнопку не выводим.
2. Хранить таблицу с 2 полями: id-comment, id-user. На каждый голос будет запись. При выводе коммента искать в таблице: голосовал ли текущий пользователь?

Но может есть более простые и быстрые методы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй вариант, индекс из обоих полей.

Если супер-популярный нагруженный сайт, можно оптимизировать, сливая старые записи в отдельную таблицу. При голосовании ставить куки, чтобы клиент пытался узнать, можно ли ему голосовать, только при отсутствие куки.

[Обсуждение похожего вопроса](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/19063/).

Comment: Вариант с куки что-то мне не нравится.Что ему писать в куки все id комментов, за которые он голосовал? А за ссылку спасибо большое. Если ответов больше не будет, то отмечу правильным